# How to load named exports with SystemJS

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs, systemjs, node-modules

If I have a lib, say `utils.js` which looks like this

```
exports.foo = function () {
    return 'foo';
};

exports.bar = function () {
    return 'bar';
};
```

Which can be used as follows

```
import {foo} from './libs/utils';

console.log(foo());
```

Not very spectacular, but I get the feeling that this problem is the origin of the issue described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42314480/how-to-import-observable-from-rx-not-angular) post. Anyway I cannot get this to work in combination with [SystemJS](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs). I have to change the code to fix it

```
import utils from './libs/utils';

console.log(utils.foo());
```

Here is my systemjs-config file:

```
SystemJS.config({
    map: {
        'plugin-babel': 'node_modules/systemjs-plugin-babel/plugin-babel.js',
        'systemjs-babel-build': 'node_modules/systemjs-plugin-babel/systemjs-babel-browser.js',
    },
    packages: {
        '.': {
            defaultJSExtensions: 'js'
        }
    },
    transpiler: 'plugin-babel'
});
```

So, it seems only the `exports` object can be loaded and not the named export. Can this somehow be fixed?

**UPDATE** I get the impression it could be fixed with [formats](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/blob/master/docs/module-formats.md#commonjs)

```
    meta: {
    './libs/utils.js': {
        format: 'cjs'
    }
}
```

But so far it gives the same problems

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This behavior is not SystemJS specific. SystemJS behaves like this since version 0.20 because this is what ES6 module interoperability is being standardized to.

When, as in your question, you are importing CommonJS modules (exported via `module.exports`) using ES6 `import`, you will only get the entire export, and you cannot immediately destructure the exported names.

However, when you are `import`ing modules which are exported via ES6 `export`, you will be able to destructure the exported names.

So, it's all by design. Guy Bedford wrote about this on his blog and referenced the module standardization that is going on for NodeJS:

> ... named exports will no longer be permitted when importing a
>   CommonJS module from an ES module, and is discussed at
>   https://github.com/nodejs/CTC/pull/60/files#diff-2b572743d67d8a47685ae4bcb9bec651R217.
>
> That is, `import { name } from 'cjs.js'`, where `cjs.js` is a CommonJS
>   module will no longer be supported, and instead will require
>   `import cjs from 'cjs.js'; cjs.name`.

An interop workaround by using `__esModule`:

> We will continue to support the `__esModule` flag in interop though,
>   allowing lifting of named exports for these cases.
>
> So if the `cjs.js` module was written:
>
> ```
> exports.__esModule = true;
> exports.name = function () {  ... }
> ```
>
> then it would be possible to have `import { name } from 'cjs.js';`, even
>   though `cjs.js` is a CommonJS module, although this `__esModule` will
>   eventually in the longer term be deprecated as well.

Comment: It's not destructuring, even if the shorthand syntax is loosely the same.