# Unhandled Promise rejection: Rx_1.Subject is not a constructor ; Zone: ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: TypeError: Rx_1.Subject is not a constructor

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, systemjs

I have an Angular 2 app, that uses `systemjs` to map/load.

Importing the `rxjs` in the project, and referencing it is fine, but when the code is deployed, it fails to construct a `Subject` variable with message:

> "Unhandled Promise rejection: Rx_1.Subject is not a constructor ;
> Zone:  ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: TypeError: Rx_1.Subject is
> not a constructor".

**Rx on systemjs:**

```
(function (global) {
var map = {
    'app': 'app',  
    '@angular': 'js/@angular', 
     // other libraries
    'rxjs': 'js/rxjs', 
};

// packages tells the System loader which filename and/or extensions to look for by default (when none are specified) 

var packages = {
    'app': { main: 'main.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'rxjs': { defaultExtension: 'js' }
};
```

The way I am instantiating the subject:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from "rxjs/Rx";

@Injectable()
export class MyService {

constructor(private http: Http) {
    let b = new Subject<string>(); // exteption HERE
    let m = b.asObservable(); 
    b.next("k");
```

all of `rxjs` is loaded fine in the browser.

---

**UPDATE**: Looking at this more, if I import `Rx` in my Angular service as:

```
import * as Rx from 'rxjs/Rx';
```

and than inspect the `Rx` object in the console, it just has a default, and `__useDefault` property getter.
Everything else, Observable, Subject is accessible through them.

Like doing :

```
var observable = Rx.Observable.create(function (observer) {
        observer.next(1);
    });
```

gets back an:

> VM1083:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'create' of `undefined`

whereas, of course:

```
var observable = Rx.default.Observable.create(function (observer) {
        observer.next(1);
    });
```

works fine.

My project is in Typescript, I have tried target compilation `es5` and `es6`.

Comment: On which line the exception?

Comment: trying to instantiate either the Subject or the Observable, been playing with commenting one out etc.

Comment: Check what `'rxjs': 'js/rxjs'` is and try importing it from `rxjs/Subject`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get unblocked after looking at [How to import `Observable` from `Rx` (not angular)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42314480/how-to-import-observable-from-rx-not-angular/42314585)

I changed my tsconfig.json module from "system" to "commonjs", and Rx lib files are being transpiled without getters.

Answer (score 4):

I was earlier importing 'import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject''.
Changed to 'import {  Subject } from 'rxjs''.
This resolved the issue for me.

Answer (score 2):

This is an example how Subject is instantiated

```
@Injectable()
export class MyService {

    public invokeEvent:Subject<any> = new Subject();

    constructor() {}
}
```

---

About Observables this is a great book about [Using Observables](https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/observables/using_observables.html).

Comment: Right, that is the line that is blowing for me; whether I put it outside the constructor, exactly like you have it, or in the constructor.

Comment: It's is constructed inline why do you need to add this to constructor?

Comment: even if i construct it inline, I still get the same constructor exception.